# Delegates C#: Pass current method EventArgs to another method

Tags: c#, delegates, eventargs

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code
    //error saying local variable named e can't be passed
    this.timer1[i].Tick += new System.EventHandler((s,e)=>this.timer1_Tick(s,e,i));
    //code
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e, int i)
{
    //code
}
```

Both the methods need the same eventArgs. Problem is because I need to pass i also to the second method. Any other way to do that?

Comment: The compiler is just confused about your naming. You're attempting to reference a second variable named `e`. Change the inner `e` to `ea` or something similar, like so: `this.timer1[i].Tick += new System.EventHandler((s,ea)=>this.timer1_Tick(s,ea,i));`

Comment: but if i do that i cant modify timer1 in the other function. i get a nullReferenceException

Comment: Changing the inner variable name shouldn't impact being able to modify anything... `EventArgs` doesn't even contain anything at all which would help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more clear about what you're trying to do - *you* don't pass event arguments to the timer's `Tick` event; the *timer* does.  All you are doing is attaching an event handler that will be called when the timer's `Tick` event is raised.  If you want the timer's `Tick` event handler to reference some part of the event args passed to the `Click` event, then store those in a class property or somewhere that the event handler can access.

Or if you have code that is in the `Tick` event handler that you want to execute *once* when the button is clicked, then move that into a separate function that can be called fro both the `Click` event and the `Tick` event.  Simeply *attaching* an event handler does NOT execute it.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timer1[i].Tick += new System.EventHandler((local_s,local_e)=>this.timer1_Tick(local_s,local_e,i));  
    //code
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e, int i)
{
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)    
{
    Timer1.Tick += (s, a) =>
    {
        //Anonymous delegate can access the sender and args
        //parameters and variables of the outer scope.
    }
}
```